# Javascript loop over getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I try to iterate using `getElementsByClassName`, but the effect i try to achieve affect all the items at once.

How can I make it work 1 item per swipe?

HTML:

```
 <div id="recog" class="cr-wrap">
            <div id="slide">
                <div class="card item"><img src="mc.svg"></div>
                <div class="card item"><img src="paypal.svg"></div>
                <div class="card item"><img src="visa.svg"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

js:

```
var wrap = document.getElementById('recog'); 
var swiper = new Hammer(wrap);  
swiper.on('swipeleft', function(){     
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');     
for ( var i=0; i < items.length ; i++ ){
    items[i].classList.add('gone');    
 }  
});
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it affect all the `.item` elements, you're not excluding any ?

Comment: I am newbie trying to learn vanilla js. would you please explain further or advice me ?..  Thanks

Comment: Then you'll have to explain what you're trying to do better. `document.getElementsByClassName('item')` gets all elements with the class `.item` in the document, isn't that what you want ?

Comment: Please post your html as well.

Comment: I try to add "gone" class to each .item every time the swipleft event is triggered. I get document.getElementsByClassName('item') then iterate over it by using for loop so i can target item.index[0] then index[1] and so on..

Comment: Yes, that's what you're doing, and you add the class `gone` to every element with the class `item` in the document. Are you trying to do something else, if so what, or isn't it adding the class as it should?

Comment: *"but the effect i try to achieve affect all the items"* So you don't want the "effect" to be applied to all items? Which items do you want the effect to be applied to? Since you only told us what you *don't* want and not what you want, we can't really help you. Maybe you only want to target `.item` elements inside `#recog`?

Comment: I want Every time the event is triggered , adding a class to each .item element one by one from index[0] to the last index

Comment: And that's exactly what you're doing ?

Comment: Do you mean 1 swipe, 1 item, until all has the `gone` class? .. If so, I updated my answer showing how to do that.

Comment: Yes, exactly this is what i try to achieve

Comment: @MohammadEltawel Check my answer, 2:nd sample does that

Comment: *"Every time the event is triggered , adding a class to each .item element one by one from index[0] to the last index"* That's exactly what you are doing now. But that doesn't seem what you want. It seems what you want is: *"Add the class "gone" to the "item" that was swiped"*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would be better, using [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll), where you can narrow the hit list even more.

```
var wrap = document.getElementById('recog');
var swiper = new Hammer(wrap);
swiper.on('swipeleft', function(){
  var items = wrap.querySelectorAll('.item');
  for ( var i=0; i < items.length ; i++ ){
    items[i].classList.add('gone');
  }
});
```

*To be noted: By using `wrap.querySelectorAll('.item');`, it target only `item`'s inside the `recog` element*

---

Update

If you want only 1 item per swipe, do like this

```
var wrap = document.getElementById('recog');
var swiper = new Hammer(wrap);
swiper.on('swipeleft', function(){
  var item = wrap.querySelector('.item');
  item.classList.add('gone');
});
```

---

Update 2

If you want only the swiped item, you should be able to do like this but it depends on how *hammer* pass the target forward.

```
var wrap = document.getElementById('recog');
var swiper = new Hammer(wrap);
swiper.on('swipeleft', function(e){
  e.target.classList.add('gone');
});
```

If this won't work, you likely need to add a swiper on each item.

Comment: unfortunately its still add the class to the whole elements :/

Comment: what do you mean by whole elements?